# This loop only allows me to choose one option for various questions although they all have their varying options

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

php code to loop through to fetch questions and answers from database. This is mainly where my problem is. I see all the questions and their options but I can only answer for  one question

```
<?php  while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $qID = $data['QID'];
            $question = $data['Question'];
            $A = $data['qA'];
            $B = $data['qB'];
            $C = $data['qC'];
    ?>  

    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td> <?php echo $qID?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $question ?> </td>
```

Loop to bring out available options per question

```
        <td>
                <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-A">A)&nbsp;     
                            <?php
                                echo $data["qA"];
                            ?>      
                        </label>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-B3">B)&nbsp;
                            <?php
                                echo $data["qB"];
                            ?>  
                        </label>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;
                            <?php
                                echo $data["qC"];
                            ?>  
                        </label>
                    </div>


        </td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
```

End of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Because all the radios have the same NAME attribute: `question-1-answers`

You should have:
`question-1-answers`  for first question
`question-2-answers`  for second question..

Do it with  `$data['QID']` , and don't forget to apply it to their ID and their LABELs too.

so your problem is that, you can only choose one from a set of same named radios, thats why you need same names for each question, but the same for all.

Comment: Okay, when i did this, I can now choose multiple options for a particular question.Any help with this?